# Equation Calculating what Day it is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Consider this word problem:

If the first day of the year is a Monday, what is the 260th day? Answer: Monday

Why does this equation work to calculate what day of the week it is:

260 = (7w + 1) [w stands for week]

How does it work and how would you even develop this equation to get the answer?

I understand that if you divide 260 by 7 you get 37.1 . Meaning all the days fit into weeks excluding one day; the first day of the week.. Monday.

But what if the first day of the year is Wednesday. What would you do then ?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic or http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/clockar.html

Answer (score 2):

Use modular arithmetic. Let's say the first day of the year is day $x$, which takes a value from $0$ to $6$, with and $0 \equiv \text{ Monday}$, so that $x$ is the number of days after the start of the first week that the transition to the new year occurs.

Now, to find what day of the week the $y$th day of the year will be, note that $y-1$ days have passed between the $1$st an $y$th day, so add on an extra $y-1$ days to whatever the first day was ($x$).
$$(y-1)+x \mod 7$$
where $... \mod 7$ is the remainder left over when you take away $7$ the maximum number of times from $...$ (that still leaves a positive integer).

In the first case, $x= \text{ Monday }=0$ and $y=260$, so 
$$(260-1)+0 \mod 7 \equiv 259-7-7-7-... \mod 7 $$$$259-7(w) \mod 7$$$$\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
Which is Monday

If Wednesday is the first day, then let $x=2$, so the $260$th day is
$$(260-1)+2 \mod 7 \equiv 2 \mod 7$$

**Edit:** the answer with less modular arithmetic.

If the $1$st day is Monday, then the $8$th, $15$th, $22$nd... days will also be Monday. These numbers have the general form $7w+1$.

If the $1$st day is Monday, then the $2$nd, $9$th, $16$th, $23$rd... days will be Tuesday. These numbers have the general form $7w+2$.

The $3$rd, $10$th, $17$th, $24$th... days will be Wednesday. These numbers have the general form $7w+3$.

In general, *why* do Mondays have the form $7w+1$? Day $1$ is a Monday, and any day a multiple of $7$ up from that will also be a Monday (or, will $\equiv 1 \mod 7$). So you can add $7$ to $1$ as many times as you want without affecting the resulting number's Mondayness.

If the first day is a Wednesday, all days that year will be shifted down $2$ from the Monday situation. Thus Monday has the form $(7w+1)-2=7w-1=7w+6$, Tuesday $7w$, W. $7w+1$, Th. $7w+2$, F. $7w+3$, Sa. $7w+4$, and Sunday $7w+5$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm already stuck on the first paragraph though :( Why do you start with Monday being zero and not 1? Why is the progress between the first day and yth day y-1? Where did you get 1 from. These are probably stupid questions.. Thanks!

Comment: They're fine questions, if you didn't understand it's my fault. For the first question, notice that choosing Monday $=0$ is completely arbitrary you could choose *any* group of $7$ consecutive numbers to represent the days of the week. However, if you take this sequence $\mod 7$, it will always reduce to $0,1,...,6$ in some order (try it for $15,16,...,21$), and I felt it most natural to 1. keep Monday associated to the lowest number and 2. to already have the sequence be $0,1,...,6$ so no further reduction is necessary.

Comment: Ask if you still don't get it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Why is it y-1 and why do you add x? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. It is greatly appreciated. Could you explain though what you mean by this: In general, why do Mondays have the form 7w+1? Day 1 is a Monday, and any day a multiple of 7 up from that will also be a Monday (or, will ≡1mod7). So you can add 7 to 1 as many times as you want without affecting the resulting number's Mondayness.

Comment: What part is unclear? Any day a multiple of 7 after a Monday is also a Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following table:

```
 Monday-1, 8, 15, 22, ...
 Tuesday-2, 9, 16, 23, ...
 Wednesday-3, 10, 17, 24, ...
 Thursday-4, 11, 18, 25, ...
 Friday-5, 12, 19, 26, ...
 Saturday-6, 13, 20, 27, ...
 Sunday-7, 14, 21, 28, ...
```

Since there exist only seven days in a week, and they always happen in the same sequence, it follows that Mondays only happen on the (1+(7n))th of the year, Tuesdays on the (2+(7n))th day, ..., Sundays on the (7+(7n))th day of the year, where n is a natural number.  Thus, all Mondays fall into the equivalence class [1], Tuesdays into the equivalence class [2], ..., Sundays into the equivalence class [7].  Thus, for the yth day of the year there exists some number (y-x) which is divisible by 7, where x is the number within the brackets and belongs to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.  For example, for the 39th day of the year (39-4)=35 which is divisible by 7.  So, the 39th day falls into the [4] equivalence class.  Consequently, the 39th day of the year is a Thursday.  Similarly, 39=((7*5)+4).

If you divide 260 by 7, you get 37 and (1/7)th (NOT 37.1... which means 37.1000... and NO approximation is NOT appropriate here).  Another way of looking at this comes as to try and divide the nth day by 7 and see what you get for the remainder.  You either have a remainder of 0, (1/7), (2/7), (3/7), (4/7), (5/7), or (6/7).  If you have a remainder of 0, then that day is a Sunday, since 0 is in the [7] equivalence class.  If you have a remainder of (x/7), then that day corresponds to the [x] equivalence class.  In your case you have a remainder of (1/7), so the day corresponds to the [1] equivalence class, which is the equivalence class for Mondays.

If the first day of the year is a Wednesday, then you can write the following table:

```
 Wednesday-1, 8, 15, ...
 Thursday-2, 9, 16, ...
 Friday-3, 10, 17, ...
 Saturday-4, 11, 18, ...
 Sunday-5, 12, 19, ...
 Monday-6, 13, 20, ...
 Tuesday-7, 14, 21, ...
```

Thus, Wednesday now belong to the [1] class, Thursdays to the [2] class, ..., and Tuesdays to the [7] (or [0]) class.  So, if you want to know the 260th day of the year, you can divide by 7 and check the remainder.  You get a remainder of (1/7) placing the 260th day in the [1] equivalence class.  Thus, if the first day of the year is "day x", where "day x" belongs to {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sundary}, then the 260th day of the year is also "day x".

Comment: Really solid explanation!! Thanks! Could you clear up some things, though? Mathematically I just don't understand why you can simply subtract x from y and divide by 7. I understand the concept of dividing by 7; but what is the purpose of (y-x) ?

Comment: @Blakasd (y-x) wasn't used as a subtraction of x from y.  I meant to say that there exists some number (y-x)... that is some number which is equal to x subtracted from y... which is divisible by seven, where x belongs to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.  That is either y minus 1, y minus 2, y minus 3, y minus 4, minus 5, y minus 6, or y minus 7 is divisible by seven (where y is a positive natural number).  There exists 7 such numbers, and in the natural number sequence, the numbers divisble by 7 are 0, 7, 14, 21, ... (7*n).  So, if you have a sequence of 7 consecutive natural numbers one of them...

Comment: is divisible by 7.